# How to get more records out of the Twitter gem?

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm banging my head trying to understand how the Twitter gem's pagination works.

I've tried `max_id` and `cursor` and they both strangely don't work.

Basically the maximum I can get out of search results is 100, and I would like to get 500.

Current code:

```
max_page = 5
max_id = -1

@data = []

for i in (1..max_page)
  t = twt_client.search("hello world", :count => 100, :result_type => :recent, :max_id => max_id)
  t.each do | tweet |
    @data << tweet
  end
  max_id = t.next_results[:max_id]
end
```

This actually tells me that `next_results` is a private method, anyone has a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which gem you're referencing (please specify a URL), I'd say intiuitively that `cursor` and `max_id` wouldn't get you what you want. However `count` would. Since you say you're only retrieving 100 results and `count` is set to `100`, that would make sense to me.

`t = twt_client.search("hello world", :count => 500, :result_type => :recent, :max_id => max_id)`

I'm assuming you're talking about the Twitter client referenced [here](http://nizhu.github.io/ruby-intro-site/blog/2013/08/01/accessing-the-twitter-api/). My first question is: What's `twt_client` and for that matter, what does its `search` method return?  It's also possible that you've unwittingly updated the gem and there's been a code base change that makes your current script out of date.

Take a look at your installed gem version and another look at the README [here](https://github.com/sferik/twitter).

Answer (score 1):

Twitter::SearchResults#next_results is private, because they try to provide uniform interface for enumeration.

Look, there's included Twitter::Enumerable in [search_results.rb](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/search_results.rb)

```
module Twitter
  class SearchResults
    include Twitter::Enumerable

    ...

    private

    def last?
      !next_page?
    end

    ...

    def fetch_next_page
      response = @client.send(@request_method, @path, next_page).body
      self.attrs = response
    end

    ...

  end
end
```

And if you look at [enumerable.rb](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/enumerable.rb), you'll see that method's Twitter::SearchResults#last? and Twitter::SearchResults#fetch_next_page are used by Twitter::SearchResults#each method

```
module Twitter
  module Enumerable
    include ::Enumerable

    # @return [Enumerator]
    def each(start = 0)
      return to_enum(:each, start) unless block_given?
      Array(@collection[start..-1]).each do |element|
        yield(element)
      end
      unless last?
        start = [@collection.size, start].max
        fetch_next_page
        each(start, &Proc.new)
      end
      self
    end

    ...

  end
end
```

And Twitter::SearchResults#each will iterate over pages until there's @attrs[:search_metadata][:next_results] in Twitter's responses. So you need to break iteration after you'll reach 500th element.

I think you just need to use each

```
@data = []
tweet_number = 1
search_results = twt_client.search("hello world", count: 100, result_type: :recent)

search_results.each do |tweet|
  @data << tweet
  break if tweet_number == 500
end
```

This post is a result of looking into gem's sources and twitter's api. I could make a mistake somewhere, since I haven't checked my thoughts in console.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I basically only updated the calculation of the `max_id` in the loop):

```
max_page = 5
max_id = -1

@data = []

for i in (1..max_page)
  t = twt_client.search("hello world", :count => 100, :result_type => :recent, :max_id => max_id)
  t.each do | tweet |
    @data << tweet
  end
  max_id = t.to_a.map(&:id).max + 1 # or may be max_id = t.map(&:id).max + 1
end
```